# How can i view the mapping configurations passed to the NHibernate by the castle activerecord?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, castle-activerecord

Is it possible to view the mapping configurations / mapping xml files passed from activerecord to nhibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the isDebug flag to true in the ActiveRecord section of your configuration file.
With this flag enabled, the NHibernate mapping files are persisted to the application directory after the ActiveRecord engine has been initialized.

Comment: thanks. Also how can i pass that settings to InPlaceConfigurationSource?